# How to append dynamically created Windows Forms controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

While I can easily accomplish in ASP.NET using AddAt(), I am trying to do the same thing in Windows Forms.

I have a panel, and while I can do a pnlMyPanel.Controls.Add(ctl) ... it always inserts it in the 0 position, when I would rather have it appended to the end, or pnlMyPanel.Controls.Count.

Am I overlooking a method or am I going to have to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how your controls are being laid out.

I assume that all of the controls in the panel have their `Dock` property set.  If so, call [`BringToFront`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx), [`SendToBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback.aspx), or [`SetChildIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx) on the new control after adding it to the panel.

If not, set the `Top` and `Left` properties (or the `Location` property) of the new control.

Comment: Then you want to call `BringToFront` after adding the control.

Answer (score 1):

AddAt functionality can be implemented by a combination of **Add** and **SetChildIndex** methods.

You can use

[SetChildIndex Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx)

to reorder the index of the child control after adding the child control.

> When SetChildIndex is called, the
>   Control referred to by the child
>   parameter is moved to the position
>   specified by newIndex and the other
>   Control references in the
>   Control..::.ControlCollection are
>   reordered to accommodate the move. The
>   control with an index value of zero is
>   at the top of the z-order, and higher
>   numbers are closer to the bottom.